# How to get other users ClaimsPrinciple in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, claims

I want to create a page with all users' claims. However, I don't quite understand whether user's ClaimsPrinciple is being stored somewhere after logout. If yes, then how can I access it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to access the claims just before calling sign-out you can read the property of type `IEnumerable<Claim>`:

```
HttpContext.User.Calims
```

Once the sign-out is done, you will no longer have that information available.

Comment: So, if I get it right, the current user can get only its own claims via HttpContext. And when a user logs out, no one is able to know, what claims he had. But is it possible for one user (admin so to say) to get claims of other users, who are currently logged in?

Comment: You're right. Client apps only have access to current user data. And user has explicitly consented to sharing that information with the client. User is the owner of his data, not the client. Logout means the user no longer wants to be identified by clients, so the session is removed (usually a cookie) and his data shouldn't be available anymore. In the context of the Identity Provider an admin could access this data for some reasons, but not in the client context.